# CheckBoxFor generating wrong HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to use this checkboxfor in MVC4 which will generate check-box and hidden field, i had given check-box checked and its value true but hidden field gets values false, I don't know what is wrong?

`@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.OrganisationClient.IsActive, new { @Id = "chkIsActive", @Value = true, @Class = "disp-none",@checked = "checked"})`

> `<input name="OrganisationClient.IsActive" type="hidden" value="false"><input class="disp-none" id="chkIsActive" value="True" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsActive field is required." name="OrganisationClient.IsActive" type="checkbox">`

Comment: where is hidden field helper

Comment: you set it check from model or by cliking it?

Comment: Hidden field is generated by checkboxfor

Comment: ok means i change my model value??

Comment: you don't need to set value via htmlattributes @Value = , the value will be taken from your viewmodel property IsActive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like that your model property is **bool** so when checkbox checked model property has `true` if not checked it has `false` thats the reason hidden field posts value `false`.

```
public bool IsActive {get;set;}
```

Comment: I am passing true in model property but still getting false in hidden field

Comment: do you see checkbox checked?

Answer (score 2):

that's how it's supposed to work, it's correct

an unchecked input type='checkbox' inside a form won't be submitted, so a hidden input with value = False was added so you won't get null instead of false in the post action

---

the hidden field will always be false and the input type=checkbox true, the checkbox will be checked if your model's property (isActive) will be true

Comment: i did'nt understood what you trying to say, can you please explain